# Sort the list in dictionary to return the first value that matches a pattern in other lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary and lists:

```
list1 = ['J', 'C', 'U', 'N']
list2 = ['K', 'G', 'E', 'Q', 'V']

dictionary = {'key1': ['key1  stuff  C_stuff  stuff',
                       'key1  stuff  J_stuff  stuff',
                       'key1  stuff  K  stuff',
                       'key1  stuff  E,V  stuff'],

              'key2': ['key2  stuff  N_stuff  stuff',
                       'key2  stuff  Q  stuff',
                       'key2  stuff  K,G,V  stuff',
                       'key2  stuff  U_stuff  stuff'],

              'key3': ['key3  stuff  K,E,Q  stuff',
                       'key3  stuff  G,K,E,V  stuff'],

              'key4': ['key4  stuff G,E  stuff',
                       'key4  stuff V  stuff']}
```

and I would like to sort the list `value` for each `key` in the `dictionary`. Thus, the list has to be sorted according first to `list1` and if `None`, then sort the list according to `list2` and if `None`, finally return the highest number delimited by commas in third column. Only return the first match for each `key`. This is the desired output:

```
'key1': 'key1  stuff  J_stuff  stuff'
'key2': 'key2  stuff  U_stuff  stuff'
'key3': 'key3  stuff  G,K,E,V  stuff'
'key4': 'key4  stuff  V  stuff'
```

Knowing that `stuff` are all different, how can I achieve such results in Python3 ?

**Edit 1**: Would it be faster to sort the list for each `key` without using `list1` and `list2` ?

**Edit 2**: Adding actual lines from my file (see below)

**Edit 3**: `'key4  stuff V  stuff'` is returned before `'key4  stuff G,E  stuff'` because if a single value is found among `list2`, then it has the highest priority than if more than one value is found.

**Edit 4**: adding code to load a sample of my text file into a dictionary like the above example.

```
import sys,re
import collections

dictionary = collections.defaultdict(list)

refseq_list = ["NC", "NG", "NM", "NP", "NR", "XM", "XP", "XR", "WP"]
ensembl_list = ["frameshift_variant", "missense_variant", "inframe_insertion", "inframe_deletion", "initiator_codon_variant", "stop_gained", "stop_lost", "splice_donor_variant", "splice_acceptor_variant", "splice_region_variant", "mature_miRNA_variant", "TF_binding_site_variant", "regulatory_region_variant", "TFBS_ablation", "TFBS_amplification", "regulatory_region_ablation", "regulatory_region_amplification", "coding_sequence_variant", "stop_retained_variant", "NMD_transcript_variant", "incomplete_terminal_codon_variant", "non_coding_exon_variant", "nc_transcript_variant", "5_prime_UTR_variant", "3_prime_UTR_variant", "upstream_gene_variant", "downstream_gene_variant", "intron_variant", "transcript_ablation", "transcript_amplification", "feature_elongation", "feature_truncation", "intergenic_variant", "synonymous_variant"]

with open("/home/test.txt") as FileObj:
    for line in FileObj:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            line_split = line.split("\t")
            dictionary[line_split[0]].append(line)
```

And copy these lines into a file

```
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   ENSG00000223972 ENST00000450305 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    2825    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 HGNC    HGNC:37102  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   ENSG00000223972 ENST00000456328 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    2086    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 HGNC    HGNC:37102  processed_transcript    YES 1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   ENSG00000227232 ENST00000488147 Transcript  intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant    -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  HGNC    HGNC:38034  unprocessed_pseudogene  YES -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl G   G   -   -   -   -   -   8/10    -   -   ENST00000488147.1:n.1067+112C>G -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   ENSG00000278267 ENST00000619216 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    874 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   HGNC    HGNC:50039  miRNA   YES -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   653635  NC_024540.1 Transcript  intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant    -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  EntrezGene  HGNC:38034  transcribed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   OK  -   -   -   -   8/10    -   -   NR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   100287102   NR_046018.2 Transcript  frameshift_variant  -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    2086    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 EntrezGene  HGNC:37102  transcribed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   102466751   NG_106918.1 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    874 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   EntrezGene  HGNC:50039  miRNA   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   102466751   NG_106918.1 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    874 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   EntrezGene  HGNC:50039  miRNA   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   ENSG00000223972 ENST00000450305 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    3049    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 HGNC    HGNC:37102  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   ENSG00000223972 ENST00000456328 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    2310    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 HGNC    HGNC:37102  processed_transcript    YES 1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   ENSG00000227232 ENST00000488147 Transcript  non_coding_transcript_exon_variant  955 -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  HGNC    HGNC:38034  unprocessed_pseudogene  YES -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl T   T   -   -   -   -   8/11    -   -   -   ENST00000488147.1:n.955A>T  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   ENSG00000278267 ENST00000619216 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    650 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   HGNC    HGNC:50039  miRNA   YES -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   653635  NR_024540.1 Transcript  non_coding_transcript_exon_variant  968 -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  EntrezGene  HGNC:38034  transcribed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  T   T   OK  -   -   -   8/11    -   -   -   NR_024540.1:n.968A>T    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   100287102   NR_046018.2 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    2310    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 EntrezGene  HGNC:37102  transcribed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   102466751   NC_106918.1 Transcript  frameshift_variant  -   -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    650 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   EntrezGene  HGNC:50039  miRNA   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636368  chr1:16841  T   ENSG00000223972 ENST00000450305 Transcript  frameshift_variant,downstream_gene_variant  -   -   -   -   -   rs62636368  G   MODIFIER    3171    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 HGNC    HGNC:37102  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636368  chr1:16841  T   ENSG00000227232 ENST00000488147 Transcript  intron_variant,frameshift_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant -   -   -   -   -   rs62636368  G   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  HGNC    HGNC:38034  unprocessed_pseudogene  YES -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Ensembl G   G   -   -   -   -   -   7/10    -   -   ENST00000488147.1:n.908+17C>A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs373847457 chr1:139233 A   ENSG00000756734 ENST00000425211 Transcript  intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant    -   --  -   -   rs373847457 C   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV LOC100996442    EntrezGene  -   misc_RNA    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  C   C   -   -   -   -   -   5/6 -   -   XR_001737578.2:n.1135+26651G>T  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0.26820.3372    0.1808  0.2029  0.3592  0.3082  0.3105  0.2765  0.2229  0.3592  gnomAD_EAS  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs373847457 chr1:139233 A   ENSG00000754812 ENST00000643524 Transcript  intron_variant  -   --  -   -   rs373847457 C   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV LOC100996442    EntrezGene  -   misc_RNA    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  C   C   -   -   -   -   -   5/5 -   -   XR_001737579.2:n.1134-18301G>T  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0.26820.3372    0.1808  0.2029  0.3592  0.3082  0.3105  0.2765  0.2229  0.3592  gnomAD_EAS  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

where

```
list1 = refseq_list
list2 = ensembl_list

`key1` = `rs141130360` and `NC_046018.2` = `J_stuff` from list1 and `downstream_gene_variant` = `K` from `list2`
```

The code provided @Ajax1234 works nicely on the example I provided first. But the actual data gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readFile.py", line 71, in <module>
    result = {a:find_result(b) for a, b in dictionary.items()}
  File "readFile.py", line 71, in <dictcomp>
    result = {a:find_result(b) for a, b in dictionary.items()}
  File "readFile.py", line 64, in find_result
    return sorted(_c, key=lambda x:(lambda c:(len(c) != max(_max) and 1 not in _max if _flag else 0, sum(c)))([refseq_list.index(h) for h in re.findall('[A-Z]+', x)]))[0]
  File "readFile.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    return sorted(_c, key=lambda x:(lambda c:(len(c) != max(_max) and 1 not in _max if _flag else 0, sum(c)))([refseq_list.index(h) for h in re.findall('[A-Z]+', x)]))[0]
  File "readFile.py", line 64, in <listcomp>
    return sorted(_c, key=lambda x:(lambda c:(len(c) != max(_max) and 1 not in _max if _flag else 0, sum(c)))([refseq_list.index(h) for h in re.findall('[A-Z]+', x)]))[0]
ValueError: 'C' is not in list
```

**Edit 5**:
This is another approach I came close but I still don't know how to output the final answer:

```
import sys,re
import collections

dictionary = collections.defaultdict(list)
refseq = []
refseq_order = []
ensembl = []
ensembl_order = []
ensembl_more_than_one_consequence = []



refseq_dict = {'NC': 0, 'NG': 1, 'NM': 2, 'NP': 3, 'NR': 4, 'XM': 5, 'XP': 6, 'XR': 7, 'WP': 8}
refseq_list = ["NC", "NG", "NM", "NP", "NR", "XM", "XP", "XR", "WP"]

ensembl_dict = {'frameshift_variant': 0, 'missense_variant': 1, 'inframe_insertion': 2, 'inframe_deletion': 3, 'initiator_codon_variant': 4, 'stop_gained': 5, 'stop_lost': 6, 'splice_donor_variant': 7, 'splice_acceptor_variant': 8, 'splice_region_variant': 9, 'mature_miRNA_variant': 10, 'TF_binding_site_variant': 11, 'regulatory_region_variant': 12, 'TFBS_ablation': 13, 'TFBS_amplification': 14, 'regulatory_region_ablation': 15, 'regulatory_region_amplification': 16, 'coding_sequence_variant': 17, 'stop_retained_variant': 18, 'NMD_transcript_variant': 19, 'incomplete_terminal_codon_variant': 20, 'non_coding_exon_variant': 21, 'nc_transcript_variant': 22, '5_prime_UTR_variant': 23, '3_prime_UTR_variant': 24, 'upstream_gene_variant': 25, 'downstream_gene_variant': 26, 'intron_variant': 27, 'transcript_ablation': 28, 'transcript_amplification': 29, 'feature_elongation': 30, 'feature_truncation': 31, 'intergenic_variant': 32, 'synonymous_variant': 33}
ensembl_list = ["frameshift_variant", "missense_variant", "inframe_insertion", "inframe_deletion", "initiator_codon_variant", "stop_gained", "stop_lost", "splice_donor_variant", "splice_acceptor_variant", "splice_region_variant", "mature_miRNA_variant", "TF_binding_site_variant", "regulatory_region_variant", "TFBS_ablation", "TFBS_amplification", "regulatory_region_ablation", "regulatory_region_amplification", "coding_sequence_variant", "stop_retained_variant", "NMD_transcript_variant", "incomplete_terminal_codon_variant", "non_coding_exon_variant", "nc_transcript_variant", "5_prime_UTR_variant", "3_prime_UTR_variant", "upstream_gene_variant", "downstream_gene_variant", "intron_variant", "transcript_ablation", "transcript_amplification", "feature_elongation", "feature_truncation", "intergenic_variant", "synonymous_variant"]

with open("/home/test.txt") as FileObj:
    for line in FileObj:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            line_split = line.split("\t")
            dictionary[line_split[0]].append(line)


def get_index_refseq(s):
    by_tabs = s.split("\t")
    by_underscore = by_tabs[4].split("_")
    return refseq_dict[by_underscore[0]]

def get_index_ensembl(s):
    by_tabs = s.split("\t")
    return ensembl_dict[by_tabs[6]]

for value in dictionary.values():
    for line in value:
        line_split = line.split("\t")
        if line_split[4].split("_")[0] in refseq_list:
            refseq.append(line)
        elif line_split[6] in ensembl_list:
            ensembl.append(line)
        elif len(line_split[6].split(",")) > 1:
            ensembl_more_than_one_consequence.append(line)

if refseq:
    refseq_order = sorted(refseq, key=get_index_refseq)

for i in refseq_order:
    print(i)
```

outputs:

```
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   653635  NC_024540.1 Transcript  intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant    -   -   --  -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  EntrezGene  HGNC:38034  transcribed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   OK  -   -   -   -8/10   -   -   NR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   102466751   NC_106918.1 Transcript  frameshift_variant  -   -   -   -   -rs62636367 T   MODIFIER    650 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   EntrezGene  HGNC:50039  miRNA   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   102466751   NG_106918.1 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -rs3210724  G   MODIFIER    874 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   EntrezGene  HGNC:50039  miRNA   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   102466751   NG_106918.1 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -rs3210724  G   MODIFIER    874 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   EntrezGene  HGNC:50039  miRNA   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   100287102   NR_046018.2 Transcript  frameshift_variant  -   -   -   -   -rs3210724  G   MODIFIER    2086    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 EntrezGene  HGNC:37102  transcribed_pseudogene  -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   653635  NR_024540.1 Transcript  non_coding_transcript_exon_variant  968 -   -   --  rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  EntrezGene  HGNC:38034  transcribed_pseudogene- -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  T   T   OK  -   -   -   8/11    -   --  NR_024540.1:n.968A>T    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   100287102   NR_046018.2 Transcript  downstream_gene_variant -   -   -   -   -rs62636367 T   MODIFIER    2310    1   -   SNV DDX11L1 EntrezGene  HGNC:37102  transcribed_pseudogene  -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

but I don't know how I can pick only the first `value` that comes for each `key`

**Edit 6**: As per request of Ajax1234, this is the input dictionary from my code above.

```
dictionary = {'rs141130360': ['rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\tENSG00000223972\tENST00000450305\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t2825\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tHGNC\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_unprocessed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\tENSG00000223972\tENST00000456328\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t2086\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tHGNC\tHGNC:37102\tprocessed_transcript\tYES\t1\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\tENSG00000227232\tENST00000488147\tTranscript\tintron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tHGNC\tHGNC:38034\tunprocessed_pseudogene\tYES\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t8/10\t-\t-\tENST00000488147.1:n.1067+112C>G\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\tENSG00000278267\tENST00000619216\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tHGNC\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\tYES\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t653635\tNC_024540.1\tTranscript\tintron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t-\t8/10\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tframeshift_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t2086\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n'], 'rs62636367': ['rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\tENSG00000223972\tENST00000450305\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t3049\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tHGNC\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_unprocessed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\tENSG00000223972\tENST00000456328\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t2310\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tHGNC\tHGNC:37102\tprocessed_transcript\tYES\t1\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\tENSG00000227232\tENST00000488147\tTranscript\tnon_coding_transcript_exon_variant\t955\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tHGNC\tHGNC:38034\tunprocessed_pseudogene\tYES\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t8/11\t-\t-\t-\tENST00000488147.1:n.955A>T\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\tENSG00000278267\tENST00000619216\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t650\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tHGNC\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\tYES\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t653635\tNR_024540.1\tTranscript\tnon_coding_transcript_exon_variant\t968\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t8/11\t-\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.968A>T\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t2310\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t102466751\tNC_106918.1\tTranscript\tframeshift_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t650\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n'], 'rs62636368': ['rs62636368\tchr1:16841\tT\tENSG00000223972\tENST00000450305\tTranscript\tframeshift_variant,downstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636368\tG\tMODIFIER\t3171\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tHGNC\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_unprocessed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs62636368\tchr1:16841\tT\tENSG00000227232\tENST00000488147\tTranscript\tintron_variant,frameshift_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636368\tG\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tHGNC\tHGNC:38034\tunprocessed_pseudogene\tYES\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tEnsembl\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t7/10\t-\t-\tENST00000488147.1:n.908+17C>A\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n'], 'rs373847457': ['rs373847457\tchr1:139233\tA\tENSG00000756734\tENST00000425211\tTranscript\tintron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t--\t-\t-\trs373847457\tC\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tLOC100996442\tEntrezGene\t-\tmisc_RNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tC\tC\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t5/6\t-\t-\tXR_001737578.2:n.1135+26651G>T\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t0.26820.3372\t0.1808\t0.2029\t0.3592\t0.3082\t0.3105\t0.2765\t0.2229\t0.3592\tgnomAD_EAS\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 'rs373847457\tchr1:139233\tA\tENSG00000754812\tENST00000643524\tTranscript\tintron_variant\t-\t--\t-\t-\trs373847457\tC\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tLOC100996442\tEntrezGene\t-\tmisc_RNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tC\tC\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t5/5\t-\t-\tXR_001737579.2:n.1134-18301G>T\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t0.26820.3372\t0.1808\t0.2029\t0.3592\t0.3082\t0.3105\t0.2765\t0.2229\t0.3592\tgnomAD_EAS\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-']}
```

Comment: What do mean with `sorted according to list1`?

Comment: @yatu it means I would like to reorder the `value` of the `dictionary` according to `list1`

Comment: You need a way to filter out "`stuff`". If "`stuff`" does not contain double spaces, split each string by them.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But you need to be more specific... Looking for a match on the first letter in the strings in values?? Splitting?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I put double space for the sake of simplicity. They are tab separated. But why would I need to filter out stuff ?

Comment: Well you want to compare the letters in `list1` and `list2` only, and thus you need an efficient way to extract them from the string.

Comment: @yatu Yes you are right, the `value` needs to be splitted first to match if it's from `list1`

Comment: And why 2 lists?? Why not append both together

Comment: @yatu sorry if its confusing but again its for the sake of simplicity, I wrote it that way because the `list2` has to be matched in another column. I will update my post to put actual lines from my file so it's clearer of what needs to be matched

Comment: why `key4` is `'key4  stuff  V  stuff'` and not `'key4  stuff G,E  stuff'`? `'G'` and `'E'` comes before `'V'` in `list2`. This question is unclear under many aspects. Seems that many users are ready to help you, but you have to clarify what is your problem

Comment: @Gsk `'key4 stuff V stuff'` comes before `'key4 stuff G,E stuff'` because if a single value was found, then it's a priority if there were more than one value.

Comment: @Law You mention if "a single value was found, then it's a priority if there were more than one value", then shouldn't `K,E,Q` be the result instead of `G,K,E,V`, as both groups belong in `list2`, and `K,E,Q` has fewer members than `G,K,E,V`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 if both members are from `list2` and if one value is found, then it has the highest priority. Otherwise, if no single value is found, then the highest number of values delimited by commas are the top priority